# Can a project which uses Entity Framework as ORM run on windows server 2003?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am working on a web application project and I am using Entity Framework to generate Model from existing database. I have deployed the project in my test environment which is windows 2003. I am sure that the connection string for my model is correct but I can't  see that the project is talking to database (checked in Event Viewer). Is that because the entity framework is only compatible with windows server 2008 and not with windows server 2003?

Comment: What database are you connecting to?  Also, is it local or remote?

Comment: it is also on the same machine windows server 2003

Comment: ENtity framework works on WS 2003.

Comment: @SidP What kind of database is it? Sql Server?  Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it on Windows Server 2003.

Entity Framework targets at most .NET framework 4.0, which is [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx) on Windows Server 2003.

I'd suggest to check

- That the connection string is really correct - do it outside Entity Framework, e.g. if you're connecting to SQL Server, try opening a connection directly with [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx).
- Check firewall settings and other permissions.

Comment: To make my connectionstring work in test environment, I am just changing the server instance which is the ip address and the user id, password which is same settings that is being used by other projects that are already running in the test environment. I can only access the test environment tmrw in office hours to check with sqlconnection.

Comment: what should I check under firewall settings that can prevent establishing a connection? Actually, I don't have idea for firewall.